# I want to fetch data

Tags: php, database, smarty

I want to fetch data from the data base but I don't know
how to fetch data in Smarty.
Please help me.

Comment: very general question. My dear atleast first tell the structure of your table or database from where you want to fetch data. What data do you want to fetch?

Answer (score 3):

You fetch it like you would normally. You then "send" it to Smarty using $smarty->assign().

Like this:

```
$name = 'John';
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->assign('firstname', $name);
```

In a Smarty template you can then use {$firstname} to access the data in $name:

`<p>Hello, {$firstname}!</p>`

Answer (score 2):

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a Frontend templating engine.  Though there are (lengthy) workarounds, you shouldn't attempt to access your model layer (the "data base") directly from a template.  Rather, you should access the database information in PHP, then pass information into the smarty templates by [assigning variables](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables).

Answer (score 1):

You dont fetch data in smarty... you only display data using smarty.
Fetching data is done in your php page, and you assign the data array to a smarty variable, that displays the data in your .tpl file.